# Is there a way to hook into every call to a @Controller method or every call to the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Java Spring MVC based web app.

I have three different `@Controller` classes with a variety of `@RequestMapping` methods that handle all web requests to the application.

Works great.

Now I have implemented a licensing system so there must be a license file in place for the application to be used.

When any web request is made, I will check the license file to make sure it is not expired and show a "License is expired, contact support" message.

My question is ...

Is there a way to hook into every call made through the Spring MVC dispatch servlet or every @Controller method so I can check licensing in one place?

I could so something like put a `licenseService.checkLicense()` in every @Controller method, but I'd rather do it in one place because it would be cleaner.

Comment: In Spring lingo, they call it an interceptor :)

Comment: @blurfus Thanks for the help, I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: @blurfus Turns out that I need slightly different "License check" logic in various specific places, so one "interceptor" probably wasn't the best approach for me.  But I think your answer was correct.

Comment: if you structure it correctly, you could use an interceptor to call a class that does the check and then re-use this class/check from the other specific places you are mentioning

Comment: @blurfus ... thanks for the suggestion.  I'd rather it was all handled in one place, so I will likely revisit this area of the product once I get 1.0 out the door.

Comment: it would be handled in one place but called from two different points as needed.  Good luck with your product :)